# Hook into iOS MobileSms application

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, message, jailbreak

I want to make a iOS tweak, that when I open the mobileSMS.app / or when I open a conversation, show a alert with the count of all the message.

don't know what header loads the mobileSMS.app. or what is the name of the class that loads the message from the sms database.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless the device is jailbroken, you can't.

Comment: It's not possible without jailbreaking; if this is what you mean, please update your question (and add the [jailbreak] tag).

Comment: yes if for a jailbreak device

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do anything with the MobileSMS.app you must add "com.apple.MobileSMS" into your bundle filter so that your tweak will load into the Messages app. Look for headers inside "ChatKit" which will be inside "theos/include" and make sure to add "tweakname_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = ChatKit" to your makefile, and #import "ChatKit/ChatKit.h" to the top of your tweak.xm

Comment: I can't find ChatKit.h, nor the folder Chatkit itself